# Excecute a query in Wordpress Admin Dashboard

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, wordpress

I'm trying to build a plugin to manage a custom table in Wordpress. In this plugin I'm gonna write 3 functions. First one to fetch data from database as you can see in the screenshot below. The second function is to update record status. And the last function is to delete a record.

My problem is I don't know how to link the function to the links in Action column. Wordpress doesn't allow me or I don't know how to send a query to to delete or update records.

I want if I click on update, status of the record I click choose will be changed then reload the page. And if I click on delete then reload the page, it will delete that record. I can write the functions but no luck to send ID query to it.

Please help. Thank you.

[image]

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Manage Custom Table
Plugin URI: http://_adddress.com
Description: Testing Plugin
Author: XXXXXXXXXX
Version: 1.0
*/
require_once('functions/functions.php');
add_action('admin_menu','ManageCustomTable_admin_actions');
function ManageCustomTable_admin_actions() {
    add_options_page('Manage Custom Table','Manage Custom Table','manage_options',__FILE__,'ManageCustomTable_admin');
}
function ManageCustomTable_admin(){
    global $wpdb;

    $data = $wpdb->get_results  ("
                    SELECT
                        id,
                        school_id,
                        added_date,
                        campus_status
                    FROM
                        table_campus
                ");
    ?>
    <style>.notice-warning {display:none;}</style>
    <table class="widefat" style="margin:20px auto; width:97%;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>School ID</th>
                <th>Added Date</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>School ID</th>
                <th>Added Date</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
        <?php
        foreach ($data as $data) {
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>'. $data->id.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'. $data->school_id.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'. $data->added_date.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'. $data->campus_status.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'; 
            ?>
            <a href=#> Update </a>
            <a href=#> Delete </a>
            <?php
            echo '</td></tr>';
        }
        ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Have a look at [Dealing With Forms](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php).

Comment: I know how to deal with forms. But in wordpress dashboard. It's doesn't work. I can't send a query to the page itself.

Comment: I don't see a `<form method='post'>` in your code?

Comment: I already tried. But the query was denied by wordpress so I took it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a php file and put your form inside that file.Then inside your plugin main php file include the file you have created.

say you create a delete.php,update.php

Then inside your php main plugin file

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Manage Custom Table
Plugin URI: http://_adddress.com
Description: Testing Plugin
Author: XXXXXXXXXX
Version: 1.0
*/
//some of your codes here

include( plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'delete.php');
include( plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'update.php');
```

your anchor tag for delete and update should have an identifier. eg the `$data-id`

```
<a href="<?php echo admin_url('admin.php?sc_update=trues&sc_id=1');?>" >Update</a>

<a href="<?php echo admin_url('admin.php?sc_delete=trues&sc_id=1');?>" >Delete</a>
```

---

**delete.php**

```
<?php 

if(isset($_GET['sc_delete']) && isset($_GET['sc_id'])){
   //[delete query here][1]
   $delete = $wpdb->delete( 'table_campus', array( 'ID' => $_GET['sc_id'] ) );
   if(false != $delete){
   //redirect to where ever you want 
   }

}
```

---

**update.php**

check whether your identifier isset

```
 <?php 
   if(isset($_GET['sc_update']) && isset($_GET['sc_id'])){
     //get the database info in using $wpdb based on $_GET['sc_id']
     //then populate the data in form below
    $data = $wpdb->get_results  ($wpdb->prepare("
                    SELECT
                        id,
                        school_id,
                        added_date,
                        campus_status
                    FROM
                        table_campus where id = %d
                "),$_GET['sc_id']);
      //let say you have the following form below as an example
    ?>
      <form style="margin-left: 300px;" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="sc_Id" value="<?php echo $data->id?>">
        <input type="text" name="sc_status" value="<?php echo $data-> campus_status;?>"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Update" name="sc_update_submit"/>
      </form>
    <?php
   } 
   //check if the update form is submitted
   if(issset($_POST['sc_update_submit'])){
     //[excute the update][1] 
     $update = $wpdb->update('table_campus', array('campust_status'=>$_POST['sc_status']),array('id'=>$_POST['sc_Id']));
     if(false != $update){
       //redirect to where ever you want
     }

   }
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for very detailed answer. I just have a question. Could I wrote 2 functions delete and update inside functions.php and just include only one functions.php instead of 2 files? And if I want to expand the plugin. I want to put all the functions inside functions.php. Is it possible?

Comment: Are you referring to theme functions.php file?

Comment: you can just add functions.php file in your plugin directory. Then dont forget to include it in your main plugin file.

Comment: I'm referring function.php - the core of the plugin, I placed it in folder "includes". If I put 2 functions delete and update in that files, I still use the same anchor?

`<a href="<?php echo admin_url('admin.php?sc_update=trues&sc_id=1');?>" >Update</a>`

`<a href="<?php echo admin_url('admin.php?sc_delete=trues&sc_id=1');?>" >Delete</a>`

Comment: yes. Just dont forget to add it in your main plugin file.

Comment: Thank you very much. When I call the function.php  Should I use `require` , `require_once` or `include` , `include_once` ? which one is the best to call the file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102552/discussion-between-louis-tran-and-jameshwart-lopez).

Comment: they almost do the same thing but I alwayse use require_once.

Comment: Get data from wordpress database is working perfectly but delete and update buttons are not working.

Comment: If I press the delete button ( pure white page will appear with link [localhost/my-url/wp-admin/admin.php?sc_delete=trues&sc_id=1]). If I press the update button (update button with text box will appear and error shows like this... Warning: Missing argument 2 for wpdb::prepare(), called in \htdocs\myurl\wp-content\plugins\pluginname123\include\update.php on line 13). That 13th line code is $data = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT id, school_id, added_date, campus_status FROM wp_table_campus where id = %d
                "), $_GET['sc_id']);   @jameshwart lopez 1

Comment: content\plugins\pluginname123\include\update.php on line 13 and defined in \htdocs\myurl\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1291   @jameshwart lopez 1

Comment: Hi @jsjq-finder I think you have different problem. try creating new question here. If you really want my help just contact me in skpype just search my name.